# Angular material MatGridListModule not working. (md-grid-tile) not showing text

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-5

Hi I am trying to use the angular material in my project. This is the code which i have written in html file.

Here i am trying to use **mat-grid** in **mat-toolbar**

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <mat-grid-list cols="3">
    <mat-grid-tile>
      left
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>
      center
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile>
      right
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</mat-toolbar>
```

I have alredy imported both **MatToolbarModule**, **MatGridListModule**
in app module and there is no error in console.
I am not able to see any text in toolbar. can any one help?

Comment: Are you using any bootstrap layouting? I had the same problem and realized putting the grid list inside a 'row' caused it

Answer (score 0):

Did you include a default theme ? [see docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started)

add `@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";` to your `styles.css` file and your toolbar should show.

I also think a `mat-grid-list` is not allowed inside a `mat-toolbar`

Comment: Yes, I added the default theme. 
So if we are not allowed to use mat-grid-list in mat-toolbar. Then how can I customize my toolbar?
Like adding buttons and search bar, text logo etc.

Comment: you can use flex-layout. https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4283

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Try this thread.

[Create a Responsive Toolbar using Angular Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200545/create-a-responsive-toolbar-using-angular-material)