# Angular Material nav bar not a responsive

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, angular-material

I've searched all over and can't seem to find an answer for this so posting here.

I have a `nav bar` that uses `mat-toolbar`. It works great on any screen tablet size or above but when the `nav bar` doesn't fit on screen the part that doesn't fit doesn't display. I've tried using bootstrap to fix the issue but haven't had any luck. Here is a stackblitz link to the repo stackblitz.com/github/jearl4/portfolio. The nav bar code is in the app->app.component.html file
[image: navbar cut off]

Here is my navbarcode:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-xs">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <h1>J.T. Earl</h1>

      <span class="navbar-spacer"></span>

      <button mat-button routerLink="/home">
        <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button mat-button routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</button>
      <button mat-button>Services</button>
      <button mat-button>Contact</button>
      <button mat-button routerLink="/capm">Capm</button>

    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
</nav>
<!-- routed view goes here -->
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

and my css:

```
.navbar-spacer {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.header {
  min-width: 319px;
  width: 100%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}
```

I've attempted the solution from [Create a Responsive Toolbar using Angular Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200545/create-a-responsive-toolbar-using-angular-material) but that hasn't solved my problem. That post is about a responsive navbar and while making the navbar responsive is probably involved in fixing my issue that is not the problem I'm trying to solve. Instead I am just trying to fix the cut off issue, the solution doesn't need to involve responsive design, although that would be welcome.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a Responsive Toolbar using Angular Material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200545/create-a-responsive-toolbar-using-angular-material)

Comment: I've tried the solutions in that post and they still haven't fixed my issue. I think this is different enough to warrant its own post.

Comment: Hi , Can you please provide your code using https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: here is the stackblitz link of the repo https://stackblitz.com/github/jearl4/portfolio

Comment: Have you found the solution? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my navigation style from a strictly horizontal layout to horizontal with a vertical side nav on small screens but this code is how I fixed my problem.

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-xs">
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">
        <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
    <h1>title</h1>

    <span class="navbar-spacer"></span>
    <div fxShow="true" fxHide.lt-md="true">
      <button mat-button routerLink="/home">
        <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <button mat-button routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</button>
      <button mat-button routerLink="/capm">Capm</button>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar>
  <mat-sidenav-container fxFlexFill class="example-container">
    <mat-sidenav color="primary" #sidenav fxLayout="column" mode="over" opened="false" fxHide.gt-sm="true">
      <div fxLayout="column">
        <button mat-button routerLink="/home">
          <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button mat-button routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About</button>
        <button mat-button routerLink="/capm">Capm</button>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav>
```